# Swapping string position in Arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a sentence: Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall. 
I want the strings to swap positions such that : Dumpty Humpty on sat wall a.

So the code that I wrote is following :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Swap{
public static void main(String []args) {
    ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
    sentence.add("Humpty");
    sentence.add("Dumpty");
    sentence.add("sat");
    sentence.add("on");
    sentence.add("a");
    sentence.add("wall");

    int size = sentence.size() ; // for finding size of array list
    int numb ; 

    if(size%2 == 0) {
        numb = 1;
    }
    else {
        numb = 0;
    }

    ArrayList<String> newSentence = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(numb == 1) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= size ; i = i+2) {
            String item = sentence.get(i);
            newSentence.add(i+1, item);
        }

        for(int i =  1; i<=size ; i = i+2) {
            String item2 = sentence.get(i);
            newSentence.add(i-1, item2);
        }


        System.out.println(newSentence);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }

    }
}
```

The code is compiling correct but when I run it, its giving an error.
What i understand of this is that I am adding strings to the array list leaving positions in between. Like adding at position 3 without filling position 2 first. How do I overcome this problem ?

Comment: Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);

Comment: "Giving an error" - would you please Copy-Paste the error message? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about your problem - you're trying to insert an element into index 1 before inserting an element at all (at index 0), and you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If you want to use your existing code to achieve this task, simply have just one loop as such:

```
if(numb == 1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1 ; i = i+2) {
        String item = sentence.get(i+1);
        newSentence.add(i, item);
        item = sentence.get(i);
        newSentence.add(i+1, item);
    }
}
```

If you want to be a bit more sophisticated a use Java's built-in functions, you can use `swap`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size-1 ; i = i+2) {
    Collections.swap(sentence, i, i+1);
}

System.out.println(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initilize `newSentence` using:

```
ArrayList<String> newSentence = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(size, ""));
```

This will let you access/skip any position in between `0` and `size`. So you can keep your rest of the code as it is.

just remember all index are being populated with empty String here.

Answer (score 0):

That is because:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= size ; i = i+2) {
            String item = sentence.get(i);
            newSentence.add(i+1, item);//Here you will face java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        }

        for(int i =  1; i<=size ; i = i+2) {
            String item2 = sentence.get(i);
            newSentence.add(i-1, item2);//Here you will face java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
```

instead of this, try following code:

```
if(numb == 1) {
         for(int i = 0; i < size-1 ; i +=2) {
              Collections.swap(sentence, i, i+1);
         }

}
```